# Double free or corruption error on object deletion

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I am trying to learn C++ by implementing a simple linked list class. In this class there is a function in which I remove a node from the linked list and try to delete the object from memory as well.

```
void List::deleteNode(Node *n, Node **h){

    Node **dp = h;

    while(*dp && (*dp)->getValue().compare(n->getValue())!=0){
       dp = &(*dp)->next; 
    }
    if(*dp == NULL){
        return;
    }

    Node *temp = *dp;

    *dp = (*dp)->next;

    delete temp;
}
```

The removal part from the list works. But when `delete temp` is called, I get a memory error:

```
*** Error in `./node.exe': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fff450d29b0 ***
```

Is this the correct way of clearing memory in C++? How should I clear the object? Or is there no need for such an operation in this case?

Comment: We're not psychics. You already know the problem! You're deleting twice, or you're corrupting memory. How shall we _guess_ the rest of your code?

Comment: Whenever I see a pointer to a pointer in C++ I get suspicious (and here indeed a `Node*&` seems to be more appropriate). Further I would suggest against manual memory management when you are just starting to learn C++ and use smart pointers instead (in fact even if you are experienced I would argue that smart pointers are the appropriate tool in most cases)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Problem pointed out by @gsamaras. Wasn't using `new` to create the objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there no need for such an operation in this case?

There is, since I assume you have created the node to be deleted with `new`.

> Is this the correct way of clearing memory in c++?

Well, one `delete` should be executed for every `new` executed.

However, the real question is-am I doing this right? Obviously not!

Imagine a single list with 3 nodes. You want to delete the one in the middle (easiest case possible). Now you make the `*dp` point to the next node from the one to be deleted, with `*dp = (*dp)->next;`.

But what about the previous node? Doesn't that break your list and create a dangling pointer?

I mean the previous node is still pointing to the node to be deleted!

So in your loop, keep track of the previous point (before the one you want to delete) and make that previous node point to the next one of `*dp`.

Then safely delete `temp`.

Of course you need to be aware of the corner cases (e.g. when the node to be deleted is the first node of the list (there is no previous node in that case)).

---

> I didn't use `new`

Then you shouldn't `delete`. That's why the program crashes at that point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `new` keyword, I didn't use it. Pretty handy to know about heap space and the stack. The rest of the code actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code deletes a memory, yes. Same time, the linked list is still unchanged. You have to modify "previous->next" in order to skip the deleted element for further usage. Something like this:

```
(*previous)->next = (*dp)->next;
delete dp;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I see in your code is that you try to shorten things and then get confused. Do it one by one and use redundancy when you need it.

First of all, what are your parameters? I read `n` and `h`. Those are two arbitrary letters. Sometimes, one can easily guess what simple names mean, like when you have something like `Rectangle(double a, double b)`. But in this case? Nope. I have no idea what `h` is supposed to be from the first glance. I can gather that it's the head node, but why do we need that? We will call this either on the head node or on an outer wrapper anyway. You call it on `List`, which looks like an outter wrapper that should already have the header node anyway. Also, you enter a node in the deletion, but the method does not delete that node and instead deletes a node with the same data value. If you want to do this, make the value the input. Maybe first write example code on how objects of your class are created and called and derive your methods from that.

Instead of all of this, use names. Like an input `Node* to_delete`.

Next step is extracting everything you need. Start generously, get everything that you think you *might* need, even if you later do not need. You can delete it later on. For example, get three nodes `previous`, `to_delete` and `next`. Take their pointers and name them clearly, like `previous_next_old`. This one for example points at the same as `to_delete`, so you might argue that it is obsolete, but if you are confused then better go with obsolete than with confusion. Again, we can change that later on.

Then create pointers like `previous_next_new` and set them accordingly, maybe based on a drawing (like in the answer by molbdnilo). Only THEN you start to remove obsolete variables. And you still let them have long descriptive names when in doubt. If you do it like that, you can end your code with `delete to_delete;` without any more consideration.

Another thing, you don't need double pointers. All you can do can be done with regular ones. If `next` is a `Node*`, then simply go like (with `Node* current`)

```
while(current != nullptr && current->value != target_value){
    current = current.next;
}
```

(Also note that I am specific about it not being nullptr here - your code that uses it as a boolean value is just fine, not saying that you should change it to how I did it, but I want to emphasize that it's also just fine to write out such things for the time being. In the refined product, I'd do it like you did, but until then, let's be verbose.)

Now, if you want I can give you a whole architecture for this, but I assume that you want to try on your own (which is better anyway). In any case, when your code works just fine, I'd recommend you to post in on CodeReview.

Edit: Another thing you might want to consider is this architecture:

```
class Node {
    //double value; << or T value or whatever
    shared_ptr<Node> next;
    //weak_ptr<Node> previous; << if double linked
}
```

This architecture would not require manual deletion, only changing pointers. In this structure, if nothing points at a node, the node dies due to the nature of smart pointer ownership. Only a ring of nodes could survive outside out of the references in active variables, and a ring is easy to avoid. But I think what you do is the better exercise.